# Find hostname of the machine that is accessing the site

Tags: php

I am trying to insert into the database the name of the device that accesses the site.

To find the ip, I do it this way:

```
$teste3 = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
```

To find out the hostname of the computer I am doing the following:

```
$hostname = gethostbyaddr($teste3);
```

But re-enter the ip of the computer and not the hostname of the computer.

**update of question:**

The ips in my network are allocated by the active directory. No active directory is registered the ip and hostname of the equipment. 
Is there a way to get the hostname through dns in php?

Comment: By hostname, do you mean user agent?

Comment: have you done `print_r($_SERVER);`? That might contain what you're looking for

Comment: I'm going to frame challenge your question. First, `REMOTE_ADDR` may not give you the client, it may give you an upstream proxy. You need to check the `X-Forwarded-For ` header and establish a chain of trust through known proxies. Second, even if you do have the client's IP, know that DNS looks can take a while and may not resolve anyway. I'd suggest deferring any attempted ip-to-name resolution until the last possible moment (eg when a user absolutely needs to know the name).

Comment: The majority of client IP addresses will not have an associated name in DNS.

Comment: @vivek_23 yes, the hostname of the user who is accessing the site

Comment: Can you provide an example of what `the name of the device` is?

Comment: @user3783243  Computer Name: POSTO3

Comment: bishop, So you mean it's not possible what I'm trying to do, right?

Comment: It is possible to do a reverse lookup if there is a name defined in DNS, which most likely there will NOT be. On my computer at home I have set the hostname to `thor`, if I wanted a reverse lookup I would have to ask my ISP, ATT, Comcast whoever to define a A/CNAME and PTR record in DNS, and since my IP can change that wouldn't work anyway.  There are dynamicDNS services but that is something a user would have to download/install, maybe pay for themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this way, using 'NTLM:

```
$headers = apache_request_headers();
      if (!isset($headers['Authorization'])){
         header('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized');
         header('WWW-Authenticate: NTLM');
         exit;
      }

$auth = $headers['Authorization'];
if (substr($auth,0,5) == 'NTLM ') {
  $msg = base64_decode(substr($auth, 5));
  if (substr($msg, 0, 8) != "NTLMSSP\x00")
    die('error header not recognised');
  if ($msg[8] == "\x01") {
    $msg2 = "NTLMSSP\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00".
        "\x00\x00\x00\x00". // target name len/alloc
      "\x00\x00\x00\x00". // target name offset
      "\x01\x02\x81\x00". // flags
      "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00". // challenge
      "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00". // context
      "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"; // target info len/alloc/offset
    header('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized');
    header('WWW-Authenticate: NTLM '.trim(base64_encode($msg2)));
    exit;
  }
  else if ($msg[8] == "\x03") {
    function get_msg_str($msg, $start, $unicode = true) {
      $len = (ord($msg[$start+1]) * 256) + ord($msg[$start]);
      $off = (ord($msg[$start+5]) * 256) + ord($msg[$start+4]);
      if ($unicode)
        return str_replace("\0", '', substr($msg, $off, $len));
      else
        return substr($msg, $off, $len);
    }
    $user = get_msg_str($msg, 36);
    $domain = get_msg_str($msg, 28);
    $workstation = get_msg_str($msg, 44);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is: [gethostbyaddr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyaddr.php)

example:

```
echo gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
```

output:
host.example.com

Edit:
first solution doesn't seem to be working for you. Here is a dirty way of actually doing a reverse request. A reverse request is:

1. The octets reversed from an IP
2. append `.in-addr.arpa`
3. a PTR request.

You could do this with [dns_get_record()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dns-get-record.php) request
Here is a little script that should work:

```
$remote_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$ip_array = explode(".", $remote_ip);

$reverse_ip_array = array_reverse($ip_array);
foreach ($reverse_ip_array as &$octet) {
    $request .= $octet;
    $request .= ".";
}

$request .= "in-addr.arpa";
$result_array = dns_get_record($request, DNS_PTR);
```

So this now stores an array;

```
array(1) {
  [0] => array(5) {
    ["host"] => string(22) "1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa" 
    ["class"] => string(2) "IN" 
    ["ttl"] => int(120)
    ["type"] => string(3) "PTR" 
    ["target"] => string(9) "localhost"
  }
}
```

So now you can verify if the array was built correctly in your code with something like [isset()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Then you can do whatever with the target:
`echo $result_array[0]["target"])`
output `localhost`

Comment: But this is what I have in the question and does not return the hostname, it returns the ip again. I need to fetch the hostname through dns, because the ip's are assigned by the active directory

Comment: Okay, I've edited my answer. This might work for you. If it doesn't I'd recommend another solution for your problem. Maybe some magic with your webserver or something.

Comment: It's not working either. I was thinking about validating my login, using NTLM authorization, is this the solution?

Comment: but I'm not getting it, can I create a question and you help me?

Comment: I created a question to use ntlm, but I'm having difficulty sending the data to the server in login validation [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56734472/use-ntlm-authorization-format-on-my-login)